# NameError: uninitialized constant AdminUser

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm new to Rails and I'm trying to assign a new Admin User in my project. When I enter AdminUser.all in rails console I get the following error:

```
NameError: uninitialized constant AdminUser
from (irb):1
from /Users/denitalambou/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/railties-5.0.2/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:65:in `start'
from /Users/denitalambou/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/railties-5.0.2/lib/rails/commands/console_helper.rb:9:in `start'
from /Users/denitalambou/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/railties-5.0.2/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:78:in `console'
from /Users/denitalambou/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/railties-5.0.2/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:49:in `run_command!'
from /Users/denitalambou/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/railties-5.0.2/lib/rails/commands.rb:18:in `<top (required)>'
from /Users/denitalambou/Sites/simple_cms/bin/rails:9:in `<top (required)>'
from /Users/denitalambou/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.4.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
from /Users/denitalambou/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.4.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
from -e:1:in `<main>'
```

Comment: There's not very much info to go on so expect a lot of questions. Have you created the model AdminUser and run the migrations?

Comment: Yes I have created the model adminuser.rb and have successfully run the migrations

Comment: Can you see that table in the schema?

Comment: Yes I see the table.

Comment: can you show the schema and the migration? Have you tried Adminuser.all?

Comment: Adminuser.all gives the same error

Comment: class CreateAdminUsersPagesJoin < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.0]

  def up
    create_table :admin_users_pages, :id => false do |t|
      t.integer "admin_user_id"
      t.integer "page_id"
    end
    add_index("admin_users_pages", ["admin_user_id", "page_id"])
  end

  def down
    drop_table :admin_users_pages
    end
    
  end

Comment: The table is called admin_users_pages. Is that what you meant to do? To access the table you'll have to call AdminUsersPage

Comment: I apologize for that mistake. I also have a table that I can see in mysql called admin_users; however, it's not listed in my migrations.

Comment: These are the tables listed in my schema: admin_users                      |
| admin_users_pages                |
| ar_internal_metadata             |
| pages                            |
| schema_migrations                |
| sections                         |
| subjects

Comment: When I run rails db:migrate, it doesn't perform any migrations. It just returns the command prompt.

Comment: I think this is why. I have admin_user as :   has_and_belongs_to_many :pages

Comment: and page has_and_belongs_to_many :admin_users

Comment: run rake db:migrate:status to see all the migrations and their status. It's strange that you have a table called admin_users and no migration for it. If this is a new app, I'd be inclined to drop the db, delete all the migration files and start afresh. However if there is a lot of data, you'll need to create a migration to create the admin_users table. Rails is obviously not recognising that table. btw, has_many through is a better option for a many-to-many relation. Are you following a tutorial or creating your own app?

Comment: If your table name is admin_users then your class would be AdminUser, and the file which contains that class should be called admin_user.rb I think that last part is incorrect.

Comment: I'm following a tutorial on lynda.com to learn rails. We are creating a cms for the first project.

Comment: These are the migrations:    up     20170324193059  Do nothing yet
   up     20170324193507  Create users
   up     20170324200829  Alter users
   up     20170324203104  Create subjects
   up     20170324203149  Create pages
   up     20170324203159  Create sections
   up     20170327162813  Create admin users pages join

Comment: I have a model called adminuser.rb with no "_" underscore.

Comment: I know you are following a tutorial, but have you tried changing the file name? Rails offers many conveniences but you have to follow its many conventions. One of those is the table/class/filename pattern. When you are in Rails Console and ask for AdminUser.all rails will then look for admin_user.rb and expect to find a class named AdminUser. 

Basically either table: admin_users, file: admin_user.rb, class AdminUser or table: adminusers, file: adminuser.rb, class: Adminuser. What you have is a mix of these two and Rails is getting confused. It turns the underscores into camel case etc...

Answer (score 2):

The error happens when you destroy the admin_user.db model from the models manually. You would have to destroy the entire ActiveAdmin using the following command -:

```
rails destroy active_admin:install
```

And then reinstall the ActiveAdmin without AdminUser

```
rails g active_admin:install --skip-users
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem. As it turns out I had forgotten an underscore in the file name admin_users.rb. Thanks for the help @margo.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. I deleted active admin model then I run it again so I got this error

```
NameError: uninitialized constant AdminUser
```

I solve it by

You have to make sure that you have admin_user.rb file in the model

```
class AdminUser < ActiveRecord::Base
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable, :trackable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, 
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :validatable
end
```

and inside the admin folder to have a file called admin_users.rb